# In a multioutput deep learning model, is there a benefit to normalizing the output dimensions if they are of different magnitudes?

Tags: neural-networks, multiple-regression, conv-neural-network, normalization

I am building a multi output deep learning model where the output consists of five dimensions (the specific architecture is a modification of YOLO). These have different magnitudes (ranges: [0, 1.2], [0, 20], [0, 1.2], [0, 1.5, 0, 2000])as shown in [image: this figure]. I was wondering if scaling the output dimensions, for example by using max-min or standard scaling, such that each predicted dimension is roughly in [0, 1] improves training (as opposed to having different scales of magnitudes in each output dimension)? Currently, the largest dimension of the (un-scaled) output monopolizes the loss value but I'm not sure if that hampers the training in some way.

### Details

Input consists of a sequence of real numbers, each number is in [0, 1]  example input: [0.15, 0.8, 0.67, 0.43]
Fully convolution network with ReLU activations and BatchNorm
Output layer is linear
Loss function is MSE for all outputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In theory, no. In practice, probably. The loss function you are minimizing is basically
$$ \min \ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K} (y_{ik} - f_k(x_i))^2 $$
where $x$ is features, $y$ is $K$-dimensional output.

Scaling the $y$'s makes no difference at all in terms of the global minima. However in practice and as you've noticed, the differing scales means that in the gradient steps the larger outcomes contribute "more" (gradients are larger) to the loss function. Thus a tiny improvement in the last output may be the same as a huge improvement in the first output where the scale is much smaller.

Whether this actually makes a difference largely depends on the dataset and your optimizer (for example if you are decaying the learning rate it might not matter much). Since neural networks generally converge to local minima and there's no downside to it, I would normalize the outputs for more stable training.

Comment: Thanks! That helps!

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Comment: @Adam Can you explain how scaling doesn't affect global minima?

Comment: I am not sure if the gradient argument is correct. Lets consider a trivial case with 1 sample and reference values $f_1 = 0.1$ and $f_2 = 100$. The loss is $L = (y_1 - 0.1)^2 + (y_2 - 100)^2$. The gradient of loss with respect to $y_1$ is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (y_1 - 0.1)$ and in general $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (y_k - f_k)$. **Only the difference between the reference and the predicted values participates in the gradient**. There isn't any multiplicative factor $y_k$ (which would correspond to the scale of each output variable).

Comment: When training neural networks, gradients are taken with respect to the model parameters - not the outcomes. More precisely (take $K=1$ for simplicity), the loss is $L = (y - f(x; W))^2$ where $f(x; W)$ is the neural network with some weights/biases $W$. Gradients are then obtained by $\nabla_W L = 2(y - f(x; W)) - \nabla_W f(x; W)$. If we scale the outcome so that $\tilde{y} = \alpha y$ for example, then $f(x; W)$ would also scale up by approximately $\alpha$ (possibly after a few iterations), which also scales the gradients up.

Comment: The main point in the argument is that with multiple outputs, the loss will be something like $L = (y_1 - f_1(x; W))^2 + (y_2 - f_2(x; W))^2$. If $y_2 >> y_1$, then the second term dominates the first (implying that gradients of the second output dominates the first). In that sense, training would be mostly optimizing for the second output to reach a local minima. In theory if we were to view $f = (f_1, f_2)$ as functions in $L^2$ space, then the global minima does not change. But in practice with finite data, finite iterations, and numerical precision it might make a difference.